# index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I don't know why I am getting an error of index. I am quite new to python and therefore am not able to figure out what to do. I think I am initialzing some wrong dimensions but I am not able to break it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

x = np.array([45, 68, 41, 87, 61, 44, 67, 30, 54, 8, 39, 60, 37, 50, 19, 86, 42, 29, 32, 61, 25, 77, 62, 98, 47, 36, 15, 40, 9, 25, 34, 50, 61, 75, 51, 96, 20, 13, 18, 35, 43, 88, 25, 95, 68, 81, 29, 41, 45, 87,45, 68, 41, 87, 61, 44, 67, 30, 54, 8, 39, 60, 37, 50, 19, 86, 42, 29, 32, 61, 25, 77, 62, 98, 47, 36, 15, 40, 9, 25, 34, 50, 61, 75, 51, 96, 20, 13, 18, 35, 43, 88, 25, 95, 68, 81, 29, 41, 45, 87])
len_x = len(x)
mean = np.mean(x)

xup = np.zeros(shape=(1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    xup[i] = (x[i] - mean) ** 2

xup_sum = np.sum(xup)
var = xup_sum / len_x
std_dev = var ** 0.5

z = np.zeros(shape = (1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    z[i] = (x[i] - mean)/std_dev

print("Mean :", mean)
print("Standard_dev :",std_dev)
print("Variance : ",var)
```

Comment: Why did you make `xup` a two-dimensional array with shape (1, 120)?  Try making it one-dimensional: `xup = np.zeros(shape=120)`

Answer (score 1):

You really should tell us where the error occurred.  But I can guess:

```
xup = np.zeros(shape=(1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    xup[i,:] = (x[i] - mean) ** 2  #<=====
```

(Similar `z` loop follows)

I added an implied `,:`.  Your `xup[i]` is indexing the first dimension.  But that is only size 1.  As created it's the 2nd dimension that is large.  `xup[0,i]` is the right indexing.

Why is `xup` 2d with the (1,120) shape?  Why not the same shape as `x` (which I assume is (120,))?  `xup = np.zeros(len_x)`.

Better yet use a proper `numpy` array calculation:

```
xup = (x-mean)**2
```

However this `xup` has the shape (100,), the same as `x`.

You are already using `np.mean(x)` which operates on the whole of `x`. Operators like `-` and `**` do so as well.

(Earlier I'd suggested using `np.zeros_like(x)`, but then realized that it would create an integer array like `x`.  Assigning float values from the calculation to that would give problems.  When doing an assign and fill loop you need to pay attention to both the shape and dtype of target array.)

Answer (score 0):

`xup` is 2 dimensional. So instead of `xup[i]` you would need `xup[0][i]`

Just fix these 2 places:

```js
xup = np.zeros(shape=(1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    xup[0, i] = (x[i] - mean) ** 2
```

And then again here:

```python
z = np.zeros(shape = (1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    z[0, i] = (x[i] - mean)/std_dev
```

This would be the file you posted above with the 2 changes:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

x = np.array([45, 68, 41, 87, 61, 44, 67, 30, 54, 8, 39, 60, 37, 50, 19, 86, 42, 29, 32, 61, 25, 77, 62, 98, 47, 36, 15, 40, 9, 25, 34, 50, 61, 75, 51, 96, 20, 13, 18, 35, 43, 88, 25, 95, 68, 81, 29, 41, 45, 87,45, 68, 41, 87, 61, 44, 67, 30, 54, 8, 39, 60, 37, 50, 19, 86, 42, 29, 32, 61, 25, 77, 62, 98, 47, 36, 15, 40, 9, 25, 34, 50, 61, 75, 51, 96, 20, 13, 18, 35, 43, 88, 25, 95, 68, 81, 29, 41, 45, 87])
len_x = len(x)
mean = np.mean(x)

xup = np.zeros(shape=(1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    xup[0, i] = (x[i] - mean) ** 2

xup_sum = np.sum(xup)
var = xup_sum / len_x
std_dev = var ** 0.5

z = np.zeros(shape = (1,120))
for i in range(len_x) :
    z[0, i] = (x[i] - mean)/std_dev

print("Mean :", mean)
print("Standard_dev :",std_dev)
print("Variance : ",var)
```

Comment: `xup` is a two-dimensional numpy array, so instead of `xup[0][i]`, it should be `xup[0, i]`.